# Foreach em checkbox para cookie

Tags: formulário, checkbox, foreach, cookies

Como eu faço um Form com Foreach em 200 Checkbox e envio os resultados dos Checkbox selecionados para um Cookie?

Comment: Vai enviar o form para o servidor e tratar os selecionados no servidor ou pretende fazer isso no client com JS?

Comment: Quero enviar p/ salvar no servidor mas estou aprendendo php e estou enrolado nessa parte do site.